# Foreach to elegant lambda LINQ

Tags: c#

Greetings I'm having a small problem, I'm having here a quite nasty triple for each loop:

```
List<Attachment> docAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
foreach (DocumentAttachment document in attachmentToAddTestRun)
{
    foreach (Attachment attachment in document.Attachments)
    {
        foreach (DocumentAttachment tDocument in TargetDocumentAttachmentMeta)
        {
            if (tDocument.Attachments.Contains(attachment) && docAttachments.Contains(attachment)) continue;
            docAttachments.Add(attachment);
        }
    }
}
```

Now is there a way to convert it to elegant Lamba expression so far ive made simple query attempt but it is less readible then foreach:

```
List<Attachment> docAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
foreach (Attachment attachment in from document 
in attachmentToAddTestRun from attachment 
in document.Attachments from tDocument 
in TargetDocumentAttachmentMeta 
where !tDocument.Attachments.Any(tDoc => !CompareTuple(tDoc, attachment)) 
|| !docAttachments.Any(doc => !CompareTuple(doc, attachment)) select attachment)
            {
                docAttachments.Add(attachment);
            }
```

Comment: Any attempt on your own?

Comment: `attachmentToAddTestRun.ForEach(document => { .. Repeat for inner collections .. })`. I doubt if its going to be elegant, though.

Comment: But of course and it eaven worked but not as lambda and its more confusing

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments - edit your question instead. Sounds like you should look at using `SelectMany`, or a LINQ query with multiple "from" clauses.

Comment: Are you sure that your inner `if` is correct? Is it correct that you it's possible to have duplicate attachments in the list? Maybe you want to use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Your main problems with your LINQ query are where you put your line breaks, more so than anything else.  Simply formatting it more conventionally would improve its readability *dramatically*.

Comment: @Servy: he does only continue the loop(so not add the attachment to the list) if both conditions are true. Either the first condition is redundant since the second condition already prevents duplicates(`docAttachments.Contains(attachment)`) or the first condition is needed as additional check, then he needs `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all get a list of all attachments:

```
var allAttachments = attachmentToAddTestRun.SelectMany(x => x.Attachments);
```

Now you can intersect with attachments from `TargetDocumentAttachmentMeta`:

```
var allAttachmentsFromMeta = TargetDocumentAttachmentMeta.SelectMany(x => x.Attachments);
var docAttachments = allAttachments.Except(allAttachmentsFromMeta);
```

If you prefer a more *compact* version:

```
var docAttachments = attachmentToAddTestRun.SelectMany(x => x.Attachments)
    .Except(TargetDocumentAttachmentMeta.SelectMany(x => x.Attachments))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Just what i needed replaced Intersect with Except and it works like a charm, Thank you